# How can I use the Scala sttp FetchBackend for handling JavaScript in html?

Tags: scala, sttp

I need to execute JavaScript in HTML responses. 
I am using sttp version 1.5.12. 
According to the documentation I just need to include `implicit val sttpBackend = FetchBackend()` but it's not working. 
See documentation at : https://sttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/javascript/fetch.html

Already included the dependency for Maven.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.softwaremill.sttp/core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.softwaremill.sttp</groupId>
    <artifactId>core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
import com.softwaremill.sttp._
implicit val sttpBackend = FetchBackend()
```

I expected to use this like the other supported backends.
Eclipse reports `not found : value FetchBackend`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're using scala-js, right?

Comment: No I'm using regular Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FetchBackend is a wrapper around [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is browser API. You can use it only with *scala-js*. 
If you open your link you will notice that dependency of **sttp** in **sbt** DSL is using three **%**, which means that it's version compiled for scala-js:

```
"com.softwaremill.sttp" %%% "core" % "1.5.12"
```

With your **maven** dependency, you're referencing *jvm* version of `sstp`, which doesn't contain *scala-js* specific backends.

You will have to just use another backend for *jvm*, like [akka-http-backend](https://sttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/akkahttp.html).

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof!